# Displaying hidden Div element at specific index using Angular Material table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a mat-table which has the following functionality: -

(1) Add / Remove rows

(2) Add data into a row using various controls (combo-box, text box, etc).

One of the controls (Addition Information) is a text box that when a ? is entered displays a hidden 'div' element that will eventually be used to hold a list of data.

The issue I have is that if I add say 3 rows and enter a ? into the 3rd row the hidden 'div' display on all 3 rows.

I need a way to somehow index each row added to the table and only display the 'div' element of that row.

Unfortunately my knowledge of HTML is limited and I am fairly new to Angular as well.

I have created a StackBlitz solution demoing my issue. [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zaobfh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[HERE'S A WORKING STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfjlx3?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** 
 I created an array `expandedCols : boolean[] = [];` that keeps track of the state (expanded or not) of your div, when you add a row, I also add one to that array with default value false, when you put ? I just change the value at index i to true.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="additionalCode" class="parent" >
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Additional Code</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index" class="parent" >
        <mat-form-field class="type">
          <input matInput (keyup)="toggleLookup($event, i)" autocomplete="off" (keydown.ArrowDown)="onDown()" placeholder="Enter ?">
        </mat-form-field>
        <div *ngIf="expandedCols[i] == true" class="child">Yah it expanded
          <button (click)="expanded = false">Close</button>
        </div>
      </td>
</ng-container>
```

TS:

```
addRow() {
    this.doAddRow();
    this.expanded = false;
    this.expandedCols.push(false);
  }

toggleLookup(event: any, i): void {
    if (event.target.value !== '?') {
      return;
    }
    event.target.value = '';
    this.expanded = true;
    this.expandedCols[i] = true;
  }
```

You should also pay attention to removing rows, do splice, you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to solve your issue is to use row local state - so put your attribute inside column collection (new column is hidden). This way you will have an opportunity to manage `expanded` property of specific row. Here is your [updated stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uuja9j?file=src/app/app.component.ts)